# ListView item with HorizontalScrollView scroll offset recycled

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview, recycle

I am having a ListView where each item contains HorizontalScrollView, I do implement a ViewHolder pattern (actually I use a custom view), so if view gets recycled and scrollview was scrolled, the scroll offset gets applied to an seemingly unrelated view (from user perspective), which is actually correct according to recyclation

but, how to get around that? **What I can think of is saving the scroll offset to the data object from adapter, but then, when should I save it?** onDetachedFromWindow doesnt seem to get called at all.

Thanks

Comment: Set a scroll listener, and save the offset from there?

Comment: yea, thats what I ended up doing and works well (btw rarely it doesnt work, but that okay with me)